# Resource on Ext-JS Framework

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Can any body please provide some good resources on **Ext-JS framework?**

I'm going to work on a project and client want to implement *MVC architecture* via **Ext-JS framework**.

Any resource on this to get started with would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best resource is http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/

It contains:

- API documentation
- Guides
- Videos
- Examples

Comment: Thanks **CD..**, Appreciate it :)
Do you have any idea about any demo web app available publicly, developed using ext-js?